# function to sample based on several conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, sampling

I am trying to prepare a function/loop which would sample a number of rows based on conditions.
I have two dataframes, the first one is a dataframe with day dates, people and their roles.

```
library(bizdays)
library(tidyverse)
from_date <- "2023-01-01"
to_date <- "2023-12-31"
create.calendar(name = "cal23", holidays = integer(0), weekdays = c("saturday", "sunday"))
daty2023 <- bizseq(from_date, to_date, "cal23") %>% as.data.frame()
daty2023 <- daty2023 %>% mutate(resource = "Michael")
daty2023 <- daty2023 %>% mutate(role = "Manager")
daty20231 <- daty2023 %>% mutate(resource = "Jose", role = "Manager")
daty20232 <- daty2023 %>% mutate(resource = "Jakub", role = "Researcher")
daty2023 <- rbind(daty2023, daty20231, daty20232)
colnames(daty2023) <- c("date", "resource", "role")
daty2023$date <-as.Date(daty2023$date)
```

The second dataframe is a tasklist with names of tasks, roles needed for these tasks, a period in which they should be performed and a number of mandays which should be assigned to each task in a given period.

```
tasklist <- data.frame(
  task = c("Task1", "Task2", "Task3", "Task4"),
  sdate = c("2023-01-12", "2023-04-18", "2023-08-25", "2023-11-03"),
  fdate = c("2023-01-12", "2023-04-25", "2023-09-26", "2023-12-29"),
  resource = c("Manager", "Manager", "Researcher", "Manager"))

tasklist <- tasklist %>% mutate(mandays = as.integer(c("1", "10", "20", "30")))
tasklist$sdate <- as.Date(tasklist$sdate)
tasklist$fdate <- as.Date(tasklist$fdate)
```

What I am trying to do now is to sample dates in which people are available from the first data frame and assign them to tasks in the second data frame based on conditions. To do that I use the `sample_n()` function.

```
df = data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(tasklist)) {
output = daty2023 %>% filter(date >= tasklist$sdate[i] & date <= tasklist$fdate[i] & role == tasklist$resource[i]) %>% sample_n(., tasklist$mandays[i]) %>% mutate(Task = tasklist$task[i])
df = rbind(df, output)
}
```

This loop allows me to match a person's availability with project task time slot and a role. However I started to wonder, whether it would be possible, and if yes how it would be possible, to add an additional condition which would assign a given amount of mandays to a person. The loop from above produces 61 mandays assigned to people. I am thinking how to make sure that i.e. 40 mandays at least are assigned to Michael, 11 to Jose and 10 to Jakub. I reckon I could probably play with the weight argument but I do not see how it could give me exactly the split I am looking for.

Comment: I guess Its hard to help since we dont have all the data. First off holidays is not defined. If I remove that then there are missing columns when binding them here ```rbind(daty2023, daty20231, daty20232)``` I cant follow what you need help with then..

Comment: Thank you for flagging this. I have edited the post and now it should be working.

Comment: So based on availability if you look at the dates that were only listed once: Jakub will have to be assigned 16 at minimum to fill those days. Unless you want to leave some unassigned? Or maybe I dont understand the dates correctly.

Comment: I would say he will have to be assigned 20 days exactly, since he is the only researcher among the available persons and we need to assign exactly 20 mandays in task 3. I hope it's clearer.